# Including WinSCP with PackageReference copies Winscp.exe in MY package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, winscp-net, packagereference

I have a problem with the WinSCP.exe file in my created NuGet package.
I reference WinSCP in my project as follows:

```
<PackageReference Include="WinSCP" version="5.17.10" />
```

After packing my NuGet package, the winscp.exe is copied to the package in contentFiles. When I reference my package in other projects/NuGet packages, the winscp.exe is also copied into the package. I don't like that, because I want to use the references and download it while package restore (obviously).

But I don't know how I can exclude the .exe from my package.

I tried this:

```
    <PackageReference Include="WinSCP" version="5.17.10" >
      <PrivateAssets>none</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>all</IncludeAssets>
      <ExcludeAssets>contentFiles;build;runtime;native;analyzers</ExcludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

This works for the first/lowest package, the .exe isn't copied and the reference is set in nuspec.
But for higher packages, which reference MY package (with reference WinSCP in nuspec), the .exe file isn't restored.

One workaround is as far as I can see, that I add for each package which is using my first/lowest package, the same reference again:

```
    <PackageReference Include="WinSCP" version="5.17.10" >
      <PrivateAssets>none</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>all</IncludeAssets>
      <ExcludeAssets>contentFiles;build;runtime;native;analyzers</ExcludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

But I don't think, that is the intended way..

I'm wondering if the nuget-package structure of the .nupkg is the source of the problem/behavior. The Winscp.dll is stored in **lib/net40**, but the Winscp.exe is in **tools/** folder. [Official Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) doesn't describe well, where .exe files should be stored and for what "tools" is for...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For reference, see [nuspec of WinSCP NuGet package](https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/master/deployment/WinSCPnet.nuspec).